# pywinauto find element by name

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have an element to be found within the tree and there's no distinctive element properties available for search according to pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements() or element.child_window() guidance.

Is there a way to access element using LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Name?
It works pretty well in VB code, but i have no clue how to locate this property in python.

Child selection by index does not work for me as well: using `ctrl_index = N` returns listing of all children in the descendant tree (`top_level_only = True` does not help), so desired element has to be located among hundreds of other children.

Here is the list of all properties that has non-zero values according to Accessibility Insights (and further below is the screenshot, representing required part of the element tree).

```
ControlType TabItem(50019)
HeadingLevel    Unknown(80050)
LegacyIAccessiblePattern.ChildId    4
LegacyIAccessiblePattern.DefaultAction  Switch
LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Name   Notes
LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Role   37
LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Selection  [tab item "Notes"]
LegacyIAccessiblePattern.State  3145730
LocalizedControlType    tab item
Name    Notes
ProcessId   11780
ProviderDescription [pid:11780,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:UIAutomationCore.DLL)]
SelectionItemPattern.SelectionContainer tab "lblSeparator"
```

[image: snapshot from Accessibility Insights]

Comment: Did you wanted to do something like `pywauto.findwindows.find_elements(title='Notes')`?

Comment: @r.ook any hints how to limit the scope? I’ve tried find_elements with parent = my_found_parent, but always get empty list. W.o limitation it starts searching forever (I’ve waited about 5 minutes and then dropped, since it’s anyway not acceptable for my case)

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I think you would need `top_level_only = False` if you want to check through all the children elements, which would explain why it might take additional time.

Comment: A better way might be, if you know which parent it is, first locate the parent, then search the children elements within the parent with what you need.

Comment: @r.ook for locating manually in parent scope (assuming ctrl_index can be applied) the problem is that it returns all the children’s down below, not limiting to only first level and there become hundreds of children to be checked manually (searching in the printed output of iter_children doesn’t help as it likely does not display meaningful details for this type of element).

Comment: Use "UI Automation" mode in `Inspect.exe`. Also `find_elements` is not recommended for use. Also check which backend is used while creating `Application(backend="uia")` object.

Comment: For legacy properties there is method `.legacy_properties()` of UIAWrapper returning dictionary. These props can't be used in `.child_window()` specification for now. We're thinking about it for next major release: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/447

Comment: Thanks for all hints, but I’ve switched to uiautomation library eventually... It’s less userfriendly, but - seemingly - implemented windows library interface in more straightforward way, so I was able to replicate VB approach for interactions with elements (like direct properties matching (so as they reflected in UI inspector) and usage of IAccessiblePatterns)